# Use of SPListCollection.Add

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, splist

Can anybody tell me how to use the [SPListCollection.Add(String, String, String, String, Int32, String, String, SPFeatureDefinition, SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee580457.aspx)?

- What is the purpose of the featureId parameter?
- What is the purpose of the listInstanceFeatureDefinition parameter?
- Which parameters are optional/required?
- What is the format of the url parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Keep running into that same codeplex link...not very helpful for this particular implementation of the method.  After some trial and error, I did get this one working and it did get around the "invalid list template" error when trying to create lists from a custom content type (ie BaseTemplate > 100000).  The function takes a SPList definition(ListToCopy) from one SPWeb and copies it to another SPWeb (NewWeb). The only missing link right now is the last parameter, docTemplateType, which I was forced to specify manually (101 - MS Word).  Not sure how to get that one from the source list.

```
public static Guid CopyListDefToAWeb(String SourceWebUrl, SPList ListToCopy, SPWeb NewWeb)
    {
        Guid newListGuid = Guid.Empty;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ListToCopy.BaseTemplate) < 10000)
        {
            newListGuid = NewWeb.Lists.Add(ListToCopy.Title, ListToCopy.Description, ListToCopy.BaseTemplate);
        }
        else
        {
            String newListUrl = ListToCopy.Title.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
            newListGuid = NewWeb.Lists.Add(ListToCopy.Title, ListToCopy.Description, newListUrl, ListToCopy.TemplateFeatureId.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ListToCopy.BaseTemplate), "101");
        }

        return newListGuid;
    }
```

Comment: Try using SPWeb.DocTypes.SchemaXml (Attributes TargetName and Type) and SPList.SchemaXml (Attribute DocTypeUrl)

Answer (score 0):

While the link you gave for MSDN clearly explain each parameter, here some example on how u can use it

http://spcore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62542#1079698